# Why @Autowiring a @Configuration class throws null pointer Junit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have a class that autowires another `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

```
@Configuration
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("api")
public class ApiConfiguration {
    private String myUrl;
}
```

....
**Class that autowires above class `ApiConfiguration`**

```
 public class Services implements anotherServices {
        
            @Autowired
            private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;
        ....

    @Override
    public Mono<SomeClass> getClassInfo(String ..., String ...) {
        return someWebClient
                .get()
                .uri(apiConfiguration.getRewardsBalance()) ---> **Null pointer**
```

Now when I autowire `ApiConfiguration` class, if I `System.out` the output I see that it's been set with whatever String I passed in, meaning My `junit` class is autowiring apiConfiguration class however, the actual implementation class throws a null pointer exception on apiConfiguration.

Test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {ApplicationConfiguration.class,ApiConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(
        initializers = ApplicationContextInitializer.class)

class AccountDetailsServicesTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;

@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
      ...
        apiConfiguration.setApi("http://localhost:8080");
      ...
```

Comment: It is a bad pattern to autowire @Configuration beans into other beans since configuration class is used to declare beans for the application context. Think of its usage as old XML configuration file

Comment: I fixed my issue by adding the ApiConfiguration class into the actual Service class constructor. The reason? When creating ServiceClass Api Instance will always be null.